# The scope of the multiplicative inverse?

Tags: inverse

First, Let $c$ denote the multiplicative inverse of $l~ (mod~ m)$, then $l\times c\equiv 1~(mod~ m)$ always hold. $l$ and $m$ are coprime. If we known $l$ and $m$, Extended Euclid's Algorithm can calculate $c$. I had known $l\in [a, b]$, $l>m$, and want to known the scope of $c$ or $l\times c$. Or add any condition can confirm the scope of $c$ or $l\times c$.

Comment: What is $\,[a,b]\,$ ? the lower common multiple? Better if you write directly $\,l.c.m\,$ , and don't mix capital and lower case letters that stand on the same category: it just makes things confusing. Oh, and what do you mean by "scope"? Perhaps an example would clear things out here.

Comment: @DonAntonio $[a, b]$ is a integer interval. "scope" is mean the value of $M^{-1}$ in a interval.

Comment: If $\,[a,b]\,$ is an interval then $\,[a,b]>m\,$ doesn't make much sense, does it? Perhaps you meant $\,m<a<b\,$ ...? And the question still is hard to understand: if $\,a<M<b\,$ then unless you know more about the integers $\,a,b\,$ you will hardly be able to say anything about $\,M^{-1}\,$ .  What you can *always* say is that in any list of $\,m\,$ *consecutive* integers there will always be exactly one representative for $\,M\,$ and for $\,M^{-1}\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio Corrected. I want to add some useful condition to known something about $c$

Answer (score 0):

So we already know

$$l>m\;,\;a\le l<b\;,\;\;a,b,l,m\in\Bbb Z$$

You can do as follows now: let $\,k\in\Bbb Z\,\;$ be s.t. $\;\;\,km\le l<(k+1)m\,\;$ , then you can make sure that *also* $\;km\le c<(k+1)m\,,\,\;c=l^{-1}\pmod m\,$

For example, if we have

$$l=37\;,\;\;m=11\;,\;\;k=3\;\;\left(\text{ because}\;\;3\cdot 11\le 37<4\cdot 11\right)$$

then we can do as follows:

$$37=4\pmod{11}\;\wedge\;4^{-1}=3\pmod{11}\implies 3\cdot 33+3=33+3=36=37^{-1}\pmod{11}$$

and of course *also* $\,33\le 36<44\,$ ...

Comment: tks. I will think about what you show.